# Cylinder rolling on an incline with offset center of gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, potential-energy

Consider a hollow cylinder with a dense 1kg weight affixed to one point on the inside.  If placed on an inclined plane, the cylinder will not roll down if there is sufficient friction.

If we gradually reduce the density of the weight toward the volume of the cylinder (edit: alternately, if we advance the cylinder's rotation), there will reach a point where it will begin to roll.

What factors determine this point?  I presume it has to do with the center of gravity with respect to the rotating axis?

Edit: This is not homework.  I'm a high school dropout.  I am considering the construction of a robot that is essentially a heavy box hung between parallel bike wheels on a single axle.  I am considering the rollover condition, i.e.: how far can the box tilt before rolling over given a known center of gravity.  The box would lean forward if climbing a slope.  If the climb is too great, the box would turn too much and roll over.  I would limit the tilt with software to prevent a rollover if I knew the limit.

Edit 2: My question is essentially this one, which has been answered: [Equilibrium and movement of a cylinder with asymmetric mass centre on an inclined plane](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/610/)

Thanks to commenter below who gave me the correct search terms.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The construction exists probably very clearly in your head, but it can't be easily decoded from your text. I suggest to produce some picture (ideally with some software), and upload it. | Furthermore, your question looks homework-like, thus you have to insert your own effort and ask for a specific physical concept.

Comment: I think you are describing the cylinder being under static equilibrium unless the center of mass is over the roll center. You can find the kinetic energy needed to overcome the potential energy of raising the center of mass so it begins to roll.

Comment: Those concepts are exactly what I was looking for, ja72. I'll do some reading on the roll center and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I have added an answer to the linked question [Equilibrium and movement of a cylinder with asymmetric mass centre on an inclined plane](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/333079)